# How to display tri-state boolean in a textbox input in MS Access vba?

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba, boolean

I rarely use **VBA Access** for maintaining our legacy application. I am using **MS Access 2007**. I am trying to use tri-state in a text-box input. In other words, I have a textbox input that is bind to Boolean field (HOME which is bit with allow NULL in SQL Server) in database; however, I need to show `1` not `-1` for `true` when user enter `1`. Similarly, there should be `0` for "false" when user enters `0` in database. The last case is: it should save `Null` in database if user enter nothing or space.
What I did so far:
Under Property Sheet for this textbox:

1. Under `Format` tab, I set `Format` field to nothing instead of true/false, on/off or yes/no as I need three state.
2. Under `Data` tab, bind `Control Source` to `Home` field.
3. Under `other` tab of property, I set `Status Bar Text` to `1=HOME, 0=Not HOME`

Problem :

1. When I enter `1`, textbox is displaying `-1` and it saves `1` in table which is good.
2. When I enter `0`, textbox is displaying `0` and saving `0`. So, this case is good.
3. When I try to enter nothing or space, it takes `0` by default.

Can anyone please tell me how do I achieve the three state for my Boolean text-box? or redirect me to the link here in Stack Overflow because I couldn't find one when I was researching in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Set the *Format* property of the textbox to: 0,0 or to: 0;0

Also, set the DefaultValue of the field to *Null*.

Try adjusting your Sub "up/down":

```
Private Sub txtHome_AfterUpdate() 
    If Me!txtHome.Value = "" Then 
        Me!txtHome.Value = Null
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: When I kept Format property to `0;0 ` and entered nothing, it sets to `0` i.e. false by default

Comment: So, the last case is not working i.e. When I try to enter `nothing or space`, it takes `0` by default.

Comment: So what is the setting for DefaultValue in the table as well as in the form?

Comment: Default value in form is NULL and when I checked it in database, the "Default Value or Binding" is empty. Doesn't it mean the default value is NULL? Home field is bit with allow NULL

Comment: No, nothing specified is not the same as _Null_. For a test, I had to write Null for that property of the field in the table.

Comment: But "" is not the same as _Null_. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per reading different online articles and Posts, I believe it is not possible to have tri-state in MS ACCESS. In other words, MS Access will take "NULL" as FALSE and save False/0/No in database. I thought of keeping it in here so that it might be helpful to some other people if they are struggling on it.